# How to loop over numbered files and also the outputs?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to run:

```
cat s_f_d_TMT161023_1306.fits.coo.1 | sed -e '/^#/d'| sort -n -k 3 | head -n 50 >> inputcoo2.list
```

and,

```
cat s_f_d_TMT161023_1307.fits.coo.1 | sed -e '/^#/d'| sort -n -k 3 | head -n 50 >> inputcoo3.list
```

and so on.

The last four characters on which I'm using the `cat` varies from *1305* and goes till *1440*. I also want the name of the output be increased by one like `inputcoo3.list` and `inputcoo4.list` and so on.

I can guess that I must run some kind of loop, but I'm new to bash and don't have any idea on how to implement it.

How do I go about it?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```sh
for i in $(seq 1305 1440)
do
  j=$((i - 1304))
  sed -e '/^#/d' "s_f_d_TMT161023_${i}.fits.coo.1" | 
    sort -n -k 3 | 
    head -n 50 >> "inputcoo${j}.list"
done
```

- this save a call to `cat`
- note that destination file will be appended
- if you want leading `0` (numerical zero, not character o) in filename, use `j="$(printf '%03d' $i)"`

Comment: 'seq' has a bash builtin of {$start..$end} - You could replace the first line with 'for i in {1305..1440}'

Comment: @xrobau thanks, I didn't know it. seq didn't exists when I start using unix.

Comment: No worries. Bash has so many useful builtins that people don't know exist 8)